iterm2 starship theme color off / not correct
I have a problem with my installed starship theme Tokyo Night: https://starship.rs/presets/tokyo-night
where in my iterm2 installed version the color is some how off:
enter image description here
Do someone know how to fix it?
I already tried to change the tokyo-night.toml file to adjust the colors. But they never match.
